# How to disable titles and arrows in angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: angularjs

How do I hide (or disable) the title and arrows when I'm using **time only**?

I'm using **angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker v1.1.4**

https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the times shown for a particular date and do not want the user to navigate out of it, an option you have is to hide the top section (the left arrow, date title and right arrow). Since the calendar is defined within a `table`, the change to do this is pretty simple; just add a `css` property to hide the `thead` of the `datetimepicker`. Note you'll probably still want to look for date change events and such and disable them. Take a look at the jsfiddle below, with a working example:

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wukk93jy/)**

Comment: I've already done this but I thought that had a way to do that in a config property or something like that. I think that "fix by css" is too ugly. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: @WilliamKennedy why is fix by css too ugly? Can you tell me more about that?

Comment: @dale.lotts Maintenence. Another dev can lost some time to figure out why in a datetimepicker is showing titles and the other not. Actually I have two different datetimepickers in my app, but when I have enough time I will replace all datepickers for datetimepicker. And some of them will need some customization. I think it will be very useful if we'd have a property like `titles: {enabled: true, model: {date: 'Some title', hour: '...', minute...}}`.

Comment: @WilliamKennedy  I can see how it would be useful to hide the title if the only view is the time view. (This may make sense in other cases also). You can override the template and remove the header - that way it works the same across all instances.

Comment: @dale.lotts I was thinking in add this customization (like the example that I gave) and send a PR. I think it would be very useful.

Comment: Are you good with keeping the change as small as possible and limited to only hiding the entire top area (the table header)? The information displayed in the title is already configurable via the before-render event.